# iOS8 Safari icon fonts not loading until browser refresh

Tags: ios, css, ember.js, fonts, safari

I have some icon fonts in an @font-face declaration in my styles that do not show in Safari iOS until the user chooses to refresh the page. The project is built on ember, so refreshes will never happen if the user does explicitly do it themselves. I know the icon fonts are loading because they show on refresh, but Safari just disregards them until I do. I have searched for days for a solution but can't find anything that works.

Has anyone run into this issue with a solve?

=== EDIT ====

here is my @font-face declaration for reference:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'designcenter';
  src:url('../fonts/designcenter.eot?-s17jdf');
  src:url('../fonts/designcenter.eot?#iefix-s17jdf') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/designcenter.woff?-s17jdf') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/designcenter.ttf?-s17jdf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/designcenter.svg?-s17jdf#designcenter') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: What version of iOS 8 are you running? They've had a few updates since 8.0.0 that included some Safari bugfixes.

Comment: the version I am using is 8.1

Answer (score 1):

So after some experimenting and changing, I found that if I took the value of *designcenter* out of quotes, either single or otherwise across the project, it seems to consistently work.

So just as a recap, iOS8 Safari cannot handle quotes for font face values. I hope this helps out anyone in the future.